# Boundary Layer Ingestion - Would it also work at supersonic speeds?

Tags: supersonic

I have searched the forum and the internet but can't find the answer to my question. Would the 10% increase in fuel efficiency from BLI function at supersonic speeds?

The 10% increase is the number I read from Bauhaus Luftfahrt and their explanation of propulsive fuselage. Which is also close to the number given by NASA.  These numbers were for typical commercial subsonic aircraft and all I want to know is if BLI would also work for aircraft travelling supersonic?

Thanks, RB

Comment: Only the outer part of the boundary layer is supersonic, so the subsonic results mostly also apply at supersonic speed.

Comment: Thank you Peter.  You are a great contributor to this forum.

Comment: boundary layer ingestion was used in the air inlet duct system of the SR-71- not to reduce drag but to improve uniformity of flow across the duct cross-section. and agree with your assessment of Peter's status!